# How can I convert my shell script to Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a shell script:

```
#!usr/bin/bash
branch_name=$1
task_name=$2
createviewset ccm -b $branch_name -t $task_name
source setenv $task_name
rest of the code
```

Now I want to convert this script to a Perl script. How can I do that? So far what I have written in the code but this code does not seem to work.

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my branch_name;
my task_name;
createviewset ccm -b $branch_name -t $task_name 
source setenv $task_name
```

Here the `createviewset` is an existing script which I am calling here.

Comment: Well, shell scripts and Perl are quite different. You can't expect code from one to just work with the other. You're going to have to *actually learn* some Perl. And that's much too broad a subject for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: The first problem I see is that you never access the comman line parameters, the next is that you don't know to call external code. There are probably more, but the pressing question is: You obviously doesn't know much perl, so why do you want to convert the script? - And as @Biffen said, learning perl is much too broad a subject for here.

Comment: @Henrik: *"you never access the comman line parameters"* The first two parameters are copied into temporary variables `branch_name` and `task_name` and the code uses those. I know it's fashionable to make bash scripts terse and cryptic, but IMO this is an excellent way to document what the code is doing

Comment: @Borodin He meant in the Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should visit http://perlmaven.com/ (available in many languages) or http://learn.perl.org/ to learn some Perl first.

Your shell script doesn't need to copy the commandline values. You also used #!usr/bin/bash which won't work because the path is either /usr/bin/bash or (more common) /bin/bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
createviewset ccm -b $1 -t $2
source setenv $2
rest of the code
```

Perl assigns all command line arguments to [the array @ARGV](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARGV). This sample prints your two arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print $ARGV[0];
print $ARGV[1];
```

Notice that the numbering starts with 0 instead of 1 as in $1 in your bash script.

Next part is running external (shell) commands in Perl: Use [the *system* command](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

system 'createviewset','ccm','-b',$ARGV[0],'-t',$ARGV[1];
system 'source','setenv',$ARGV[1];
```

Notice that the *source* command won't work because a Perl script is not a shell script and can't "include" Bash script. I appreciate that you're trying to use Perl for your problem, but it looks like Bash is the much better tool for this.

Comment: I don't think the OP deserved it, but this is a damn good answer. The only thing I'd change is to use `my ($branch_name, $task_name) = @ARGV`. That way the code is more meaningful and corresponds better with the OP's original bash code, and the issue of indexes is irrelevant

Comment: You're right. I usually try to avoid copying everything as it's very expensive if heavily used, but it would be better for education.

Comment: I think *"very expensive"* is unrealistic. Very few applications consist of a central bash script where the copies would be made millions of times. The main reasons to use `$1`, `$2` etc. in a bash script would be for brevity's sake, and there is *no reason* to access `@ARGV` elements directly in Perl code